# Spring @RequestHeader validate for blank string

Tags: spring, validation, javax-validation

I have a spring service that receives a header parameter like this:

```
@RequestHeader(name = "token", required = true) String token
```

but it only validates if the header is present and not if it is blank or just spaces,

if I add `@NotBlank` or `@Valid` makes no change,

How can I annotate a header parameter so it is validated for blank strings?

thnx in advance,

Answer (score 0):

**Validate Request Header** [docs](https://www.yawintutor.com/how-to-validate-request-header-in-spring-boot/)

The spring boot allows to validate a request header as like other request parameters. The annotation `@Validated` is used to validate the request header. And add `@NotBlank` for validation

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;


@RequestHeader(name = "token", required = true) @NotBlank String token
```

Comment: not spring-boot